# Toad import from Excel to MySQL imports fewer rows than expected

Tags: mysql, excel, toad, data-import

I have a 13MB .xlsx file and I want to import the first sheet into a table in a Mysql server with Toad 6.3.0.642

It works almost fine but it imports 4264 rows and it should be 4284. It doesn't throw any errors and shows Read rows=4264 and Write rows=4264.

How can I debug this process, in order to find which are the missing rows?

Comment: No, there are no hidden or filtered rows

Comment: I exported the sheet to CSV with Excel and imported that, and the row number is correct now

Comment: No, but I think the CSV method is a good idea for importing into a DB table anyway, so I'll stick to that

Comment: Check for 'blank' rows. Toad discards rows with no data in them.

Comment: I took out the blank rows and now there are only 3 more rows in the CSV imported table than the Excel imported table. They don't have a PK so I can't find the differing ones however